# odoo v13 : website.rewrite URL redirection issue

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, odoo, odoo-13

Using the existing model website.redirect:
https://mywebsite-oerp.odoo.com/web#action=147&model=website.rewrite&view_type=list

I have set up this URL redirection :

**URL FROM**: /event/stage-test-online-2023-02-21-2023-02-23-1990/register

**URL TO**: /event/stage-test-2023-02-21-2023-02-23-822/register

**ACTION** : 301 permanently moved

**WEBSITE** : eyme-yoga

[image]

I have tried with the whole url too : https://www.mywebsite.com/event/stage-test-online-2023-02-21-2023-02-23-1990/register

I have tried the ACTION: ***308 rewrite*** too but it does not allow route having hard parameters (only the general route is proposed : /event/<model("event.event", "[('website_id', 'in', (False, current_website_id))]"):event>/register)

but anyway, the redirection that i want does not take place.

Any clue how to manage this with the functional? odoo tools ?
...without having to use my custom module (already done):

```py
@http.route(['/sama-actu.php', '/sys/course_apply.php',],
    type='http', auth="public", website=True)
    def urls_redirect_events(self, page=1, **searches):
        if request.website.name == "Samadeva":
            return werkzeug.utils.redirect('http://www.samadeva.com/event', 301)
```

Comment: It seems your code looks good. Can you check if your function executes properly (add something to throw an error ) and *request.website.name* value?

Comment: My module works fine... that's not the purpose of my question. My question was : how to manage it with standard odoo functionalities... thanks any way for your post